# Removing horizontal muntins from 1950s split pane windows

Tags: windows

Is it possible to change to look of old exterior windows by removing the center horizontal muntin on a 1940-1950’s split 2 pane window?  I would like to remove the divider, remove both pieces of glass, and inset a solid piece of glass, so I no longer have a divided pane. These muntins are solid wood, not fake.  They look like this (this photo is NOT my house)...

https://retrorenovation.com/2011/05/09/replacement-windows-for-a-1950s-house/

This old window style really dates the house (it’s cape cod style) and I only need to do the 2 windows that face the street.

Answer (score 1):

Most windows like that were built as an assembly with finger joints or other connections. It's not easy to remove a single component. You'll probably need to remove the glass and cut the muntins off, then mill them to the shape of the stiles to which they attach.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the work involved, keep in mind that you will still have single-pane windows. Once you are going to all that trouble, it may make sense to have a window company build modern (e.g., at least double-pane) replacement windows. These companies are used to measuring and building exactly what is needed - as long as it is a rectangle, they can do it pretty easily. The only catch is that the frame may end up being a different material or style from what you currently have. If that is a historic preservation issue then even removing the muntins may be prohibited. But if that is not a historic preservation issue then full window replacement really does make sense.